# Pass Function to Functional Component in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an `ItemForm` component in a react-native expo app I would like to use for both Creates and Updates. It is a functional component which I am trying to pass a handler from a parent component to either create a new item or update an existing item. I am having trouble understanding how to pass the `onPress` handler down from the parent Class Component down to the functional child form Component.

Parent Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import ItemForm from './components/ItemForm';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class App extends Component {
  handleSubmit = ({ name }) => {
    alert(name);
    // todo: get form data and create or update database
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Card>
        <ItemForm onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit}/>
      </Card>
    </View>
  );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

ItemForm.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Button, Card, Icon, Input } from "react-native-elements";

export default function ItemForm({ onSubmit }) {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>Add an Item</Text>
      </View>
      <Card
        containerStyle={{
          height: "80%",
          margin: 0,
          elevation: 1,
          borderWidth: 0,
          shadowOpacity: 0,
          shadowRadius: 0,
        }}
      >
        <Input
          label="Item Name"
          labelStyle={styles.itemText}
          placeholder="Name Here"
          onChangeText={(name) => setName(name)}
        />
        <Button
          icon={
            <Icon
              name="check-circle"
              size={20}
              style={{ paddingRight: 10 }}
              onPress={onSubmit({name: name})}
            />
          }
          title="Save Item"
        />
      </Card>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
  header: {
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingTop: 40,
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
  itemText: {
    fontSize: 25,
  }
});
```

This is currently throwing:

```
onSubmit is not a function. (In 'onSubmit({name: name})', 'onSubmit' is undefined)
```

I've tried various different syntaxes of passing or calling the function by reading the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html) but I run into a lot of errors like `Please attach a method to this component` and I can't seem to get past this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `onPress` should be a function that calls `onSubmit`, not the return    value of calling `onSubmit` (`onPress={onSubmit({name: name})}`).
- `onPress` needs to be on the Button.
- You need to pass down `this.handleSubmit` from the parent component, and not a function that returns `this.handleSubmit` (`onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit}`):

So in App:

```
<ItemForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
```

In ItemForm:

```
    <Button
      onPress={() => onSubmit({name: name})}
      icon={
        <Icon
          name="check-circle"
          size={20}
          style={{ paddingRight: 10 }}
        />
      }
      title="Save Item"
    />
```

[demo](https://snack.expo.io/pxyLgohSy)

Comment: Thank you! Using this syntax is one of the instances where I run into the

`Please attach a method to this component`

message and it doesn't seem to be passing correctly still?

Comment: here is a snack with a repro: https://snack.expo.io/@twoy/supportive-juice-box

Comment: Hmmm so your answer works on the snack but not in my app. I am console logging props as they are being passed into the child component ItemForm.js and I don't see onSubmit. One key thing I left out of this is that I am using react-navigation and Stack.Screen. Is that potentially obscuring the props from being passed down? Here is what the console log of the props object looks like from immediately inside the ItemForm.js Component:

`Object {"navigation": Object {...},"route": Object {...},}`

Comment: Thanks @el-aoutar-hamza your answer worked and I found the issues with my setup it was unrelated. Thanks again!